# Sidekiq process dies silently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I have 2GB droplet on Digital Ocean and things seem to be working until last week and all of sudden my sidekiq processes seems to be disappearing enqueuing all the jobs. I have SWAP Memory also enabled. Is there any way to be certain that it's because of memory before i go ahead and upgrade the server

**Last 30 days history**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the memory was the reason, then probably Linux OOM killer killed the process. you can confirm that using

```
grep -i 'killed process' /var/log/messages
- or -
dmesg | egrep -i 'killed process'
```